# PyQt slider for different digits

Tags: python, pyqt, qwidget, pyqtgraph

I'm new to python and i'm trying to create application using pyqt and pyqtgraph. In application I would like to add slider using which different digits of number can be changed, i.e for number 150.0 change 1, 5, 0 and 0 seprately by typing on the up and down buttons near these numbers (see picture).

[image]

How this can be done in python? Is there any avaliable widget for this in pyqt or pqtgraph, or i should create my oun widget to perform this? Or instead of slider another ui element should i use to do this?

Comment: You want the numbers to be modified from a slider, and also that they can be modified by the buttons?

Comment: I want to have ui element with the functionality shown in picture (when the arrows are typed, the corresponding number must be changed). I don't know for this i may be don'n need to use slider.

Comment: Then you just want to change each number by pressing the buttons. Do you want a widget per digit or all within a widget? If yes, how many digits do you want to display?

Comment: I want one widget for all. The maximum number of digits is 4

Comment: One last query, let's say the number shown is 159 and press the button at the top of digit 9, the number to be displayed is 150 or 160?

Comment: the number should become 160

Comment: pyqt4 or pyqt5?

Comment: I'm using pyqt5